# DataFrame/Dataset join not producing correct results in Spark 2.0/Yarn

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

We have a cluster running Apache Spark 2.0 on Hadoop 2.7.2, Centos 7.2. We had written some new code using the Spark DataFrame/DataSet APIs but are noticing incorrect results on a join after writing and then reading data to Windows Azure Storage Blobs (The default HDFS location). I've been able to duplicate the issue with the following snippet of code running on the cluster.

```
case class UserDimensions(user: Long, dimension: Long, score: Double)
case class CentroidClusterScore(dimension: Long, cluster: Int, score: Double)

val dims = sc.parallelize(Array(UserDimensions(12345, 0, 1.0))).toDS
val cent = sc.parallelize(Array(CentroidClusterScore(0, 1, 1.0),CentroidClusterScore(1, 0, 1.0),CentroidClusterScore(2, 2, 1.0))).toDS

dims.show
cent.show
dims.join(cent, dims("dimension") === cent("dimension") ).show
```

outputs

```
+-----+---------+-----+                                                         
| user|dimension|score|
+-----+---------+-----+
|12345|        0|  1.0|
+-----+---------+-----+

+---------+-------+-----+
|dimension|cluster|score|
+---------+-------+-----+
|        0|      1|  1.0|
|        1|      0|  1.0|
|        2|      2|  1.0|
+---------+-------+-----+

+-----+---------+-----+---------+-------+-----+
| user|dimension|score|dimension|cluster|score|
+-----+---------+-----+---------+-------+-----+
|12345|        0|  1.0|        0|      1|  1.0|
+-----+---------+-----+---------+-------+-----+
```

which is correct. However after writing and reading the data, we see this

```
dims.write.mode("overwrite").save("/tmp/dims2.parquet")
cent.write.mode("overwrite").save("/tmp/cent2.parquet")

val dims2 = spark.read.load("/tmp/dims2.parquet").as[UserDimensions]
val cent2 = spark.read.load("/tmp/cent2.parquet").as[CentroidClusterScore]

dims2.show
cent2.show

dims2.join(cent2, dims2("dimension") === cent2("dimension") ).show
```

outputs

```
+-----+---------+-----+                                                         
| user|dimension|score|
+-----+---------+-----+
|12345|        0|  1.0|
+-----+---------+-----+

+---------+-------+-----+
|dimension|cluster|score|
+---------+-------+-----+
|        0|      1|  1.0|
|        1|      0|  1.0|
|        2|      2|  1.0|
+---------+-------+-----+

+-----+---------+-----+---------+-------+-----+
| user|dimension|score|dimension|cluster|score|
+-----+---------+-----+---------+-------+-----+
|12345|        0|  1.0|     null|   null| null|
+-----+---------+-----+---------+-------+-----+
```

However, using the RDD API produces the correct result

```
dims2.rdd.map( row => (row.dimension, row) ).join( cent2.rdd.map( row => (row.dimension, row) ) ).take(5)

res5: Array[(Long, (UserDimensions, CentroidClusterScore))] = Array((0,(UserDimensions(12345,0,1.0),CentroidClusterScore(0,1,1.0))))
```

We've tried changing the output format to ORC instead of parquet, but we see the same results. Running Spark 2.0 locally, not on a cluster, does not have this issue. Also running spark in local mode on the master node of the Hadoop cluster also works. Only when running on top of YARN do we see this issue.

This also seems very similar to this issue: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-10896

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was fixed by the pull request submitted in https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-17806